# Beginner JavaScript array issue

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

Currently I have to work on a simple site that takes three values from the user, adds them up and provides an average. Lecturer helped me put this together but finishing it up tonight I can't get the average to come out correct.

*This is my HTML:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Demonstrates some logic errors" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, average, errors" />
  <meta name="author" content="997993X"  />
  <title>Average numbers</title>
  <script src="badaverage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Average numbers</h1>
    <p>Click the button to enter a series of numbers to average</p>
    <button id="enter">Enter your first number</button>
    <p><span id="numberList"></span></p>
    <button id="calculate">Calculate the average</button>
    <p><span id="result"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

*And this is my JS:*

```
/*
   JavaScript used with 'average.html'
*/

"use strict";
//Global variables accessible to all functions
var numbers = [];  //create an empty array
var enterButton = null;  //global variables must be initialised
var calculateButton = null;

/* Get a number from the prompt
*  If a valid number add to array, if not give error message to user
*  Display the updated array of numbers on the web page
*  Make the Calculate button visible
*/
function enterNumber(){
    var number = prompt("Enter your number");
    var number = Number(number);   // No idea what thi does, added by prof
    if (isFinite(number)) {    // test what is entered is a number   
        numbers.push(number);   //add the number entered to the end of the array 
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter a valid number");
    }
    document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = "The numbers you have entered so far are: " + numbers;  //diplay a list of number entered
    enterButton.textContent = "Enter your next number"; //change the label on the Enter Button
    calculateButton.style.visibility = "visible";     //show the button  - uses the CSS property of the elenment
}       
/* Calculate the sum and average of the array of number
*  Display the results on the web page
*/
function calculateAverage(){
    var average = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1 ; i < numbers.length; i++){    
        total = numbers[i];   //add each number in the array to the cumulative total 
    }
    average = total/i;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The total of your numbers is " + total + " and their average is " + average;
}

function init(){
        enterButton = document.getElementById("enter");  
        calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
        calculateButton.style.visibility = "hidden";    //hide the Calculate button until some numbers are entered
        enterButton.onclick = enterNumber;
        calculateButton.onclick = calculateAverage;


}

window.onload = init;
```

I've used the stock Firefox debugger to find the error and it's late but I'm pretty sure I've gone afoul on line 35 of the JS during the for loop's initialise statement. *"numbers[i]"* becomes undefined after the loop has ran three times resulting in the average being NaN.

Sorry for the rookie question I feel like i'm staring at it in the face, any help would be appreciated to send this student to bed.

Comment: I guess you wanna do `total += numbers[i];`, and `var i = 0` otherwise you skip the first element

Comment: Yups,. thats the solution :) @JonasW Didnt read your comment earlier or i wouldnt have posted as answer.

Comment: @nandita its a common practice to answer although someone else already pointed out the solution ... so feel free to undelete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays' index starts at 0, so you should initialize your for loop with a `var i = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from 0.
Also add all the numbers using  `total += numbers[i];`

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++){    
        total += numbers[i];   //add each number in the array to the cumulative total 
    }
```

```js
/*
   JavaScript used with 'average.html'
*/

"use strict";
//Global variables accessible to all functions
var numbers = []; //create an empty array
var enterButton = null; //global variables must be initialised
var calculateButton = null;

/* Get a number from the prompt
 *  If a valid number add to array, if not give error message to user
 *  Display the updated array of numbers on the web page
 *  Make the Calculate button visible
 */
function enterNumber() {
  var number = prompt("Enter your number");
  var number = Number(number); // No idea what thi does, added by prof
  if (isFinite(number)) { // test what is entered is a number   
    numbers.push(number); //add the number entered to the end of the array 
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a valid number");
  }
  document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = "The numbers you have entered so far are: " + numbers; //diplay a list of number entered
  enterButton.textContent = "Enter your next number"; //change the label on the Enter Button
  calculateButton.style.visibility = "visible"; //show the button  - uses the CSS property of the elenment
}
/* Calculate the sum and average of the array of number
 *  Display the results on the web page
 */
function calculateAverage() {
  var average = 0;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i]; //add each number in the array to the cumulative total 
  }
  average = total / i;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The total of your numbers is " + total + " and their average is " + average;
}

function init() {
  enterButton = document.getElementById("enter");
  calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
  calculateButton.style.visibility = "hidden"; //hide the Calculate button until some numbers are entered
  enterButton.onclick = enterNumber;
  calculateButton.onclick = calculateAverage;


}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
.abc {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Demonstrates some logic errors" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, average, errors" />
  <meta name="author" content="997993X" />
  <title>Average numbers</title>
  <script src="badaverage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Average numbers</h1>
  <p>Click the button to enter a series of numbers to average</p>
  <button id="enter">Enter your first number</button>
  <p><span id="numberList"></span></p>
  <button id="calculate">Calculate the average</button>
  <p><span id="result"></span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `total = numbers[i]` *completely reassigns* total. If you want to calculate the average, *add* to `total` instead.

Another issue is that arrays are *zero*-indexed, not one-indexed; start at `i = 0`, not `i = 1`. Or, even better, use an array method, which has better abstraction and doesn't require manual iteration. `forEach` is one option, but `reduce` is more appropriate for when you're turning an array into a single value:

```
const total = number.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

```js
/*
   JavaScript used with 'average.html'
*/

"use strict";
//Global variables accessible to all functions
var numbers = []; //create an empty array
var enterButton = null; //global variables must be initialised
var calculateButton = null;

/* Get a number from the prompt
 *  If a valid number add to array, if not give error message to user
 *  Display the updated array of numbers on the web page
 *  Make the Calculate button visible
 */
function enterNumber() {
  var number = prompt("Enter your number");
  var number = Number(number); // No idea what thi does, added by prof
  if (isFinite(number)) { // test what is entered is a number   
    numbers.push(number); //add the number entered to the end of the array 
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a valid number");
  }
  document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = "The numbers you have entered so far are: " + numbers; //diplay a list of number entered
  enterButton.textContent = "Enter your next number"; //change the label on the Enter Button
  calculateButton.style.visibility = "visible"; //show the button  - uses the CSS property of the elenment
}
/* Calculate the sum and average of the array of number
 *  Display the results on the web page
 */
function calculateAverage() {
  const total = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  const average = total / numbers.length;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The total of your numbers is " + total + " and their average is " + average;
}

function init() {
  enterButton = document.getElementById("enter");
  calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
  calculateButton.style.visibility = "hidden"; //hide the Calculate button until some numbers are entered
  enterButton.onclick = enterNumber;
  calculateButton.onclick = calculateAverage;


}

init();
```

```html
<h1>Average numbers</h1>
<p>Click the button to enter a series of numbers to average</p>
<button id="enter">Enter your first number</button>
<p><span id="numberList"></span></p>
<button id="calculate">Calculate the average</button>
<p><span id="result"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, really appreciate it!

Comment: I would add the initial reducer as `0` if the array is empty / got one element

Answer (score 0):

Points corrected in below code

- Arrays always starts with index 0.
- You need to add total to itself in the loop like `total = total + newNumber`

Here's working solution -

```js
/*
   JavaScript used with 'average.html'
*/

"use strict";
//Global variables accessible to all functions
var numbers = [];  //create an empty array
var enterButton = null;  //global variables must be initialised
var calculateButton = null;

/* Get a number from the prompt
*  If a valid number add to array, if not give error message to user
*  Display the updated array of numbers on the web page
*  Make the Calculate button visible
*/
function enterNumber(){
    var number = prompt("Enter your number");
    var number = Number(number);   // No idea what thi does, added by prof
    if (isFinite(number)) {    // test what is entered is a number   
        numbers.push(number);   //add the number entered to the end of the array 
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter a valid number");
    }
    document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = "The numbers you have entered so far are: " + numbers;  //diplay a list of number entered
    enterButton.textContent = "Enter your next number"; //change the label on the Enter Button
    calculateButton.style.visibility = "visible";     //show the button  - uses the CSS property of the elenment
}       
/* Calculate the sum and average of the array of number
*  Display the results on the web page
*/
function calculateAverage(){
    var average = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++){    
        total += numbers[i];   //add each number in the array to the cumulative total 
    }
    average = total/i;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The total of your numbers is " + total + " and their average is " + average;
}

function init(){
        enterButton = document.getElementById("enter");  
        calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
        calculateButton.style.visibility = "hidden";    //hide the Calculate button until some numbers are entered
        enterButton.onclick = enterNumber;
        calculateButton.onclick = calculateAverage;


}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Demonstrates some logic errors" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, average, errors" />
  <meta name="author" content="997993X"  />
  <title>Average numbers</title>
  <script src="badaverage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Average numbers</h1>
    <p>Click the button to enter a series of numbers to average</p>
    <button id="enter">Enter your first number</button>
    <p><span id="numberList"></span></p>
    <button id="calculate">Calculate the average</button>
    <p><span id="result"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```